# Radio button array get id using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a issue with radio button array. I have 1 timer when timer is 0 and select 1 radio button then that value get in jquery.

```
<li>
<span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[][1]" id="cmbans[][1]" value="Value1" />
</li>
<li>
<span class="option">Option2  :  Value2 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[][2]" id="cmbans[][2]" value="Value2" />
</li>
<li>
<span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[][3]" id="cmbans[][3]" value="Value3" />
</li>
```

This radio button name or id get in jquery but problem is this is array so how can i get this. Pls help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are using those IDs? `$('input[id="cmbans[][3]"]')`? http://jsfiddle.net/aVqgs/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get ypur problem correctly. I'm not sure if this one helps you..

Change your html like this..

```
<li>
<span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[]" id="cmbans1" value="Value1" />
</li>
<li>
<span class="option">Option2  :  Value2 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[]" id="cmbans2" value="Value2" />
</li>
<li>
<span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[]" id="cmbans3" value="Value3" />
</li>
```

Now create jquery to get the value like this..

```
if(timer == 0){
var value = $('#id of radio').val();
}
```

Comment: NOt working. My problem is i have 4 radio button with dynamic id. Means  4 radio button id is cmbans1,cmbans2,cmbans3,cmbans4 with array and when timer is 0 then automatic submit the form with that ids in another page. THis is the question and answer functionality using php & jquery.

Comment: i have some tried but no any more idea in the jquery so pls help me for this.

Comment: If you are doing an exam app, then only one answer should be submitted and the user who is doing the exam should select an answer, right? otherwise why we will know which should be submitted?? I think you have problems with the idea of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is but you can't define an associative array using your inputs name attribute.
Try

```
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[]" id="cmbans_1" value="Value2" />
<input type="radio" name="cmbans[]" id="cmbans_2" value="Value2" />
```

You can select using jquery all elements with id starts with cmbans to get an array of radio buttons.  When the form is submitted your webserver will parse the inputs names into an array.

Answer (score 0):

To select element whose ids' have special characters you have to escape these special characters. In your case `[` and `]`, also your choice in id naming is quite stramge

```
$("#cmbans\\[\\]\\[1\\]").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Id of each and every HTML element must be unique within the HTML document.

you can define HTML array of elements in following manner

e.g

And for accessing html array elements using jquery assign same class to all elements within that html array and then we will iterate through elements of HTML array on basis of class

e.g 
           $('.xyz').each(function()
          {
              alert($(this));
          });

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I didn't get much about what exactly you want but take a shot with following.
PHP looks like:

```
$str = ''
for(i = 0:i < 4;i++){
str.= '<li>';
str.= '<span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>';  
str.= '<input type="radio" name="cmbans" value="'.cmbans[][i].'" />';
str.= '</li>';
}
echo str;
```

HTML Looks like:

```
    <li>
    <span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
    <input type="radio" name="cmbans"  value="Value1" />
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
    <input type="radio" name="cmbans" value="Value2" />
    </li>
    <li>
    <span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
    <input type="radio" name="cmbans" value="Value3" />
    </li>
     <li>
    <span class="option">Option1  :  Value1 </span>  
    <input type="radio" name="cmbans" value="Value4" />
    </li>
```

And Jquery Looks like:

```
if(timer == 0){
   var _value = $('input:radio:checked').val();
   //do something with _Value.
}
```

I hope this is what you want...